# Filter objects with attr. aatr is dynamic

Tags: javascript, node.js

I been at it for a while.

Help please

```
var obj 1 = [{name: "tim", dob: 010101},{name: "tom", dob: 010101},{name: "dim", dob: 010101}]
```

attr is object that will have dynamic properties. 
ex: `attr = {dob: 010101, name: tom}`
results will have the filter results of the attr matching the obj1

Thanks in advance

```
 function filter(attr){
var results = []
}
```

Comment: Show for real what you've tried. Where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: Simply iterate over the array and compare the properties of each object? What are you having problems with? Iterating over the array? Iterating over the properties of an object? Comparing two values?

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = [];
obj1.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    if(element.name== attr.name && element.dob == attr.dob){
        newArray.push(element);
    }
});
```

That would solve your problem?